# Henstock, Differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

Does anyone know, where I can find the proof of necessary and sufficient conditions for differentiating under the integral sign in case of Henstock integral? Here are the theorems but not all the proofs:

> *Necessary and sufficient conditions for differentiating under the integral sign*
>   Erik Talvila
>   [arXiv:math/0101012](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101012)
>
> We give necessary and sufficient conditions for differentiating under the integral sign an integral that depends on a parameter. The conditions require the equality of two iterated integrals and depend on being able to integrate every derivative. The Henstock integral is thus used in an essential way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bartle's *A modern theory of integration* has it on [pp. 199-200](https://books.google.com/books?id=6-9royzoBL8C&pg=PA199).

Comment: Is it really a Henstock integral in the book? The theorem looks different.

Comment: @green113: Yes, it is. Scroll to [page 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=6-9royzoBL8C&pg=PR9), "The purpose of this monograph is to present an exposition of a relatively new theory of the integral (variously called the "generalized Riemann integral", the "gauge integral", the "Henstock-Kurzweil integral", etc.)".